# PHP preg_replace expression to remove URL parameter

Tags: php, preg-replace, url-parameters

I wanted to remove all occurrences of specific pattern of a parameter from a URL using preg_expression.  Also removing the last "&" if exist
The pattern looks like: make=xy ("make" is fixed; "xy" can be any two letters)

Example:

```
http://example.com/index.php?c=y&make=yu&do=ms&r=k&p=7&
```

After processing `preg_replace`, the outcome should be:

```
http://example.com/index.php?c=y&do=ms&r=k&p=7
```

I tried using:

```
$url = "index.php?ok=no&make=ae&make=as&something=no&make=gr";
$url = preg_replace('/(&?lang=..&?)/i', '', $url);
```

However, this did not work well because I have duplicates of make=xx in the URL (which is a case that could happen in my app).

Comment: why are you using `lang` when you want to replace `make` ?

Comment: sorry that lang meant to be make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need RegEx for this:

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?ok=no&make=ae&make=as&something=no&make=gr&";

list($file, $parameters) = explode('?', $url);
parse_str($parameters, $output);
unset($output['make']); // remove the make parameter

$result = $file . '?' . http_build_query($output); // Rebuild the url
echo $result; // http://example.com/index.php?ok=no&something=no
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using:

```
$str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$query = array();
parse_str($str, $query);
var_dump($query);
```

This will return to you the query as an array. You could then use http_build_query() function to restore the array in a query string.

But if you want to use regexp:

```
$url = "index.php?make=ae&ok=no&make=ae&make=as&something=no&make=gr";
echo $url."\n";
$url = preg_replace('/\b([&|&amp;]{0,1}make=[^&]*)\b/i','',$url);
$url = str_replace('?&','?',$url);
echo $url;
```

This will remove all make in the URL

Comment: both ways didn't work for me.  the first way returned NULL and the second one returned strange output

Comment: I edited the post, in my test, the regex works well. In the first way, i forgot that parse_str has the array passed by reference, and does not return it.

Answer (score 0):

with `rtrim` you can remove last `&`

```
$url = rtrim("http://example.com/index.php?c=y&make=yu&do=ms&r=k&p=7&","&");
$url = preg_replace('~&make=([a-z\-]*)~si', '', $url);
```

Comment: if `make` comes directly after `index.php?`, it is not replaced.  Also the values of all `make=`'s are not removed as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "index.php?ok=no&make=ae&make=as&something=no&make=gr";
$url = preg_replace('/(&?make=[a-z]{2})/i', '', $url);
echo $url;
```

Comment: if `$url = "index.php?make=xx&ok=no"` .. the outcome will leave extra `&` after `index?` .. which is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Just by using preg_replace

```
$x = "http://example.com/index.php?c1=y&make=yu&do1=ms&r1=k&p1=7&";

$x = preg_replace(['/(\?make=[a-z]*[&])/i', '/(\&make=[a-z]*[^(&*)])/i', '/&(?!\w)/i'], ['?','',''], $x);
echo $x;
```

> And the result is: http://example.com/index.php?c1=y&do1=ms&r1=k&p1=7

Hope this will be helpful to you guys.